# Always getting NULL in controller when passing values from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to pass a `string` value from javascript to controller.
The ActionResult method is called properly but the parameter type of string always getting null.

JavaScript:

```
var contents = 'M1234';
$.get('/Sched/GetInformation/' + contents, {},
                function (data, status) {
                    if (!data.success) {
                        alert('test');
                    }
                });
```

Controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "")]
public ActionResult GetInformation(string mID)
{
      bool superficialCheck = true;

      return Json(new { success = superficialCheck },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note:
Controller Name is SchedController

`mID` is always getting `null` value

Comment: Have you tried changing mID to id?

Comment: Do you have a specific route defined with `...{mID}`? (otherwise it would need to be `string id`). In any case, you should be using `$.get('@Url.Action("GetInformation", "Sched")', { mID: contents }, function() {...`

Comment: Hello can you try "?mId="+contents or "/mId/"+contents ... please also post your route settings in Global.asax ?

Comment: @sachin, is `id` is case sensitive ?

Comment: @User1674987, No.

Comment: @WickStargazer, where to put `"?mId="+contents`

Comment: '/Sched/GetInformation?mId=' + contents or '/Sched/GetInformation/?mId=' + contents

Comment: @sachin, You are correct. I am getting the value after changed to `id`. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `route` doesn't have parameter `mID` defined.

If you're using the default route, that usually defines a parameter `id`. You can either **name the paramater `id`** in your action method, or **specifically pass `mID`** when you call from javascript or **define a route with parameter `mID`**.

Comment: You are correct. I am getting the value after changed to id. Thank You very much.